# Can spark data source API get query plan informations?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If a spark user call dataframe.count, is there a way for the data source API to know?

We have a custom implementation of spark 3's data source api. Knowing which function is being called would allow us to do some optimization to the data source.

I'm relatively new to spark so I'm not sure if I missed something or which is the best approach.

Comment: If you have a custom implementation of the dataframe api of spark 3, I believe you should be able to just customize and override the `count()` function in that custom implementation. If you can customize it, you can add code in the `count()` function to do whatever you want.

Comment: Also note, counting is ideally optimized based on the format of the input data that you use. Try to use a column based storage format, like `parquet`, which will make aggregations much faster and optimized.